# why does java starts treating everything as a String once it has encountered a string in System out statement?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

i am learning java and practicing it daily,i wrote the following code and wondered about the output

```
class test
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
System.out.println(1+2+ " = " +10+2);
}
}
```

here the output was **3=102**,and wondered about the following "Java starts treating everything as a String once it has encountered a string in System out statement"

can anyone explain this ?i m confused why does it accept it as string?

Comment: what output did you expect? Also your output should have been `3 = 102` and not `3=102`

Comment: for `3 = 12` you should write `System.out.println(1+2+ " = " + (10+2));`

Comment: @jlordo 10+2=12 ;i expected 3=12,i am confused i already closed " " why does it now treats as string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java parses program text without regard to the types of expression. As motivation, consider if they were fields written after the method in the class. So, as string concatenation and addition share the same operator, we have

```
1+2+ " = " +10+2
```

is equivalent to

```
((((1+2)+ " = ") +10)+2)
```

Folding constants, we have

```
(((3+ " = ") +10)+2)
(("3 = " +10)+2)
("3 = 10"+2)
"3 = 102"
```

Comment: @mahalakshmi Well, it's specified with a grammar, from which you can derive operator precedence and associativity.

Answer (score 1):

`+` with String becomes String concatenation operator and not a addition operator.

`1 + 2 + 10 + 2` will be equal to 15 as a simple addition
while
`1 + 2 + "+" + 10 + 2` will be treated as
1. `1 + 2` output will be 3 as it is a simple addition
2. `3 + = (String)`  output will be  `3=` because it is String concatenation
3. `3= (String) + 10 + 2` will be String concatenation and not a simple addition so output will be `3=102`

Answer (score 1):

> "Java starts treating everything as a String once it has encountered a
>   string in System.out statement"

It's completely wrong. `System.out` is a static instance of the class `PrintStream`.
PrintStream has many overloaded versions of the `println()` method and the one in your example accepts `String` as parameter. You are using **+ operator** and it's for ***concatenation*** of Strings unless the operands are both numbers.

```
System.out.println(3+5+"."); // println(String) is invoked.
System.out.println(3+5); // println(int) is invoked.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  (1+2) -- two integres additoin will result int 3
  (3 +  " = ") -- this will result int + String = String (concatination)
  ("3=") -- String + any thing (data type) will result String
```